# UIWebView blank page rotation

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I'm creating a UIWebView with a blank page using the following code.

```
- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];

    UIWebView *wv = [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds] autorelease];
    wv.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self.view addSubview:wv];
}
```

When rotating the device from portrait to landscape or vice versa the page's content becomes bigger than the webview's bounds and black areas appear. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `self.view` (the webview's parent view) may not have the correct autoresizing masks.  A subview's autoresizing mask will only fill up to the container bounds.  If the webview's parent view does not have it's autoresizing mask setup correctly, then the webview's autoresizing masks won't look correct, either.  You seem to be setting up the webview properly (not using `CGRectZero` on `initWithFrame` without ever setting an initial size), so your current implementation should work barring nothing else has been setup funny in your view controller.

Comment: Autoresizing mask set up correctly, there is no problem with webview's or it's superview's bounds. I decided to hide webview before loading any resource.

Comment: Try creating your own view for `self.view` instead of relying on `[super loadView]` to create it for you.  Or put an `NSLog(@"%@",self.view)` after `[super loadView]` to see if there's an issue with that before you start sending that frame to your webview.  You could also try using `self.view.frame` instead of `self.view.bounds` in `[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame]`.  You can't just say there's no problem with any of the view's rects.  Something is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;

See also: [UIWebView+SFHFStringMetrics](https://github.com/ldandersen/scifihifi-iphone/tree/master/UI/)

Comment: `scalesPageToFit` doesn't help